# How to install GNU paint?

Tags: software-installation, gnu, paint

I am trying to install GNU paint on Ubuntu 16.04 but am not able to do it. Can anyone please help me how to install GNU paint on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## About

From the [GNU Paint](https://www.gnu.org/software/gpaint/) project page:

> GNU Paint (gpaint) is a simple, easy-to-use paint program for GNOME,
>   the GNU Desktop. Gpaint starts as a port of xpaint and takes
>   advantages of features unique to the GNOME environment. Gpaint is
>   licensed under the GNU GPL, version 2 or later.

Curent Features:

- Drawing tools--ovals, freehand, polygon, text, with fill or shallow for polygons and closed freehand.
- Cut and paste by selecting irregular regions or polygons.
- Print support using gnome-print (still flaky, will be improved upon next release)
- Print support using gnome-print (still flaky, will be improved upon next release)
- Editing multiple image at the same time without runnng multiple instance of the image editor
- All image processing features present in xpaint

## Installation

You can install Gnu Paint / gpaint by

```
sudo apt install gpaint
```

Comment: Installed it but am not able to see it.

Comment: Open up a terminal and enter 'gpaint' and confirm by enter.